# Toolbar weird elevation

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar

If you set

App style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Style:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Toolbar.ThemeOverlay" parent="Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/pickup_primary_text</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/pickup_accent</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/pickup_primary_text</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/pickup_primary_text</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/pickup_primary</item>
        <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
        <item name="android:elevation">4dp</item>
    </style>
```

Toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:toolbar="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar.ThemeOverlay"
    toolbar:titleTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar.TitleText" />
```

[image]

But if I set it directly in the toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:toolbar="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar.ThemeOverlay"
    toolbar:titleTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar.TitleText" />
```

[image]

I thought it was a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=173915) but they say that not.

Why?

Comment: It needs to be `elevation` instead of `android:elevation`

Comment: but why? and if you set elevation it dont put the bottom shadow.